# FTP programs not working. Router blocking maybe?

Tags: ftp, notepad++, filezilla

When I use ftp programs like filezilla and notepad++ I have problem to transferring files to my ftp-server. This problem exist only at my home. My theory is that my routers are making the problem and my question is how can you check if it is the router that causing the problem?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a firewall rule that allows everything / turn off your router firewall, if it then works, you know its that, so before you turn it back on add the ftp ports in there.

It might also be windows firewall blocking the ftp program also.

Comment: What port should i open for ftp transfer?

Answer (score 0):

check the firewall rules to see if standard ftp access is allowed.  Alternately you can try an ssh client like winscp to make a secure connection and see if this goes through